# Center text within textview

Tags: android

I have a textview inside of a linear layout. I have the textview set to match_parent, both height and width.

Essentially the textview is the size of the screen. But the text is staying aligned to the top left. Is there a way to have it centered?

I have android:gravity and android:textAlignment set to center.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

or just

`android:gravity="center"`

to center text in a TexView.

EDIT: try removing `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` or the layout_weight attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Large Text"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textAlignment="center" />
```